# Let $G$ be a group of order $120$, let $H≤G$ with $|H|=40$. Prove that there exists $K$ such that $K\unlhd G$, $K≤H$, and $|K|≥20$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $120$, let $H≤G$ with $|H|=40$. Prove that there exists $K$ such that $K\unlhd G$, $K≤H$, and $|K|≥20$.

I think this is associated with the action of the left coset of $H$. Maybe the kernel.
But I don't know why the kernel of this action commutes with every element of $G$

Comment: Where did you get this problem? If it's from a book, what topics are discussed in the chapter it appears in? I'm curious about what methods can be used to solve a problem like this.

Answer (score 4):

Let $C$ be the set of left cosets of $H$, and consider the action of $G$ on $C$ by left multiplication, that is $g_1 * (g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$. This induces a group homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow S_C$. Let $K = \ker \phi$. Observe that $K \leq H$ and $K \lhd G$. Since $|G| = 3|H|$ and $G/\ker \phi \simeq \phi(G) \leq S_C \simeq S_3$, we find $\dfrac{3|H|}{|\ker\phi|} = |\phi(G)|$ divides $6$, so $\dfrac{|H|}{|\ker\phi|}$ is either 1 or 2. Regardless, $|K| \geq 20$.

Comment: why K is the normal subgroup of G

Comment: It is the kernel of a homomorphism whose domain is G.

Comment: So what...
ϕ(K)=1...

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: For any $k \in K$, we find $\phi(k) = \sigma_k$ where $\sigma_k(gH) = (kg)H$ is identity. For $g = e$, we find $H = kH$ or $k \in H$. Then $K \leq H$. Since a subgroup is normal if and only if it is the kernel of a group homomorphism, it follows that $K \lhd G$.

Comment: Perhaps it could be also mentioned that the kernel $K$ of this action is the intersection of the conjugates of $H$.